# how do you write the output of the linearray in a csv file in php?

Tags: php

I need to login to bunch of servers tail a log and write the output to a file (output needs to be appended to the file so that the file contains entry from each server). Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
chdir('c:/php');

include('Net/SSH2.php');

$servers=array('server1','server2','server3','server4');

foreach ($servers as &$value1) {

    $server=$value1.".example.com";
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($server);
        if (!$ssh->login('user', 'passwd')) {
            echo 'unable to login '.$value1;

            continue;
        }
    $file_name="/apps/logs/was/gws1/perf.log";
    $line= $ssh->exec("tail -50 $file_name");
    $rawLines = explode("\n", $line);
    $lines = array();
    $fp = fopen('C:/perf_log.csv', 'w');
    echo $rawLines;

        fputcsv($fp, $rawLines);


fclose($fp);
}
exit

?>
```

this is creating one line in the file. I need each line in the $rawFiles to be new line in the perf_log.csv. Any ideas how I could do this in php?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `w` when opening the file, which is truncating any previously existing lines:

`Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.`

What you actually want is `a`:

`Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.`

Comment: I tried that the same result. Each line becomes a cell in the csv file. I need each line as new line in csv. It does not have to be a csv file.

Comment: @user1471980 Then don't use a CSV, use a text file instead? and just use `fputs` instead.

Comment: sorry I am new to php. What if, I wanted to keep appending to the file?

Comment: the `a` flag indicates that you wish to write to the file starting at the end, any `fputs` commands after that will be appended to the file by nature using the `a` flag on fopen.